# Does ID property in binding model pose a threath to overposting?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm quite new in MVC and can't get my head around a possible overposting threath. I have an "Event" model which contains an Id property. When a user, for example, wants to edit an existing "Event", I use this property for fetching the "Event" I need to update from a collection of "Events".

I tried to decorate the Id property with the [BindNever] or [Editable] attribute which results in an Id property of 0 as the property no longer binds after a post. This, of course, generates problems when I want to use this Id property for fetching an "Event" from the collection.

So I leave the property undecorated. But it feels unnatural as this property should not be editable by a user. Using a ViewModel does not solve my problem as an Id property would still be needed.

In all examples I find online, an Id property is always part of a binding model. Does this pose threats to possible overposting? I assume not as, when working with Entity Framework, for example, the Id property is not Editable as it is autoincremented. A user would still be able to change the Id in order to update another "Event" though but in the case of my application, this generates no issue as a user is able to edit any "event" he wants

Model:

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult EditEvent(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            var eventToEdit = _events.GetEvent(id.Value);
            return View(eventToEdit);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult EditEvent(Event postedEvent)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (postedEvent == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                var eventToUpdate = _events.GetEvent(postedEvent.Id);
                eventToUpdate = _events.EditEvent(postedEvent, eventToUpdate);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(EventDetails), new { id = eventToUpdate.Id });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return View(postedEvent);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does ID property in binding model pose a threat to overposting?

Yes, if you're using this id as a lookup for editing then you need to write a check that ensures that the user is allowed to perform the edit on the data.

```
public IActionResult EditEvent(Event postedEvent)
{
    //Make sure the current user can edit the posted event
    if(!CanUserEditEvent(postedEvent.Id, User.GetUserId()) return Forbid();

    //User can edit this event so continue normally
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
        ...
}
```

Furthermore, ensure that other "read-only" or unused properties of your model that are exposed on the view and action are not then used as a lookup or saved. A view model can help with this by allowing you to define a subset of your domain model properties.

Comment: Also one thing to add to the above answer you are thinking to much with view models etc. The controller can and will receive any data possible the only way to be certain that your user is authorized to edit an event is with the above answer by @Show. A malicious user can try to hit your controller with a random id to mess with your application. This is where access rights come in.

Also i would recommend storing information about access rights at session. Once a user is logged you add to the sessions his access rights and check at the controller. SessionExtensions are a life-saver